# Node Server not working in console Node Js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run local host in my browser utilising Node Js..

Node Server function is not working.

I have switched from mac to windows.

Is there different functions for terminal and command prompt?

```
C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\deeplake4> node server
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\deeplake4\server.js:5:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\deeplake4>
```

Comment: `npm install` to install your dependencies

Comment: Thanks sorted! I cannot get console.log working. Would you know how to get this to respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
`npm i --save body-parser`

Comment: Thanks sorted! I cannot get console.log working. Would you know how to get this to respond?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>



      <title>Deeplake</title>
      
      <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
     
      <script src="./libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./libs/underscore-min.js"></script>


</head>



<body>

      <script>

          $.getJSON('articles.json', function(data) {
              console.log('it worked!');
          });
          
      </script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Console in Chrome Dev Tools dose not seem to respond at all to my JQuery:

Comment: <script>

          $.getJSON('articles.json', function(data) {
              console.log('it worked!');
          });

      </script>

Comment: Console in Chrome Dev Tools dose not seem to respond at all to my JQuery: 

<script> $.getJSON('articles.json', function(data) { console.log('it worked!'); }); </script>

Answer (score 1):

```
 npm i body-parser --save
```

Above command will save this dependency in package.json

Comment: Thanks Sorted

Console in Chrome Dev Tools dose not seem to respond at all to my JQuery: 

<script> $.getJSON('articles.json', function(data) { console.log('it worked!'); }); </script>